# Run perl CGI script in Apache on Docker container

Tags: docker, apache, perl, ubuntu

I have already made the script and ran it on my VM from /usr/lib/cgi-bin. I need this script to be running the same way in a docker container. I am fairly new to using docker and currently have the below config in my Dockerfile. I'm not sure if i am putting the script in the right directory or not or if I'm even doing this the right way. After running the container on port 8080 I tried to go to `ip_adress:8080/cgi-bin/shipping.pl` but this just says that the site can't be reached. I have already tried changing the COPY to `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data shipping.pl .` to see if maybe permission weren't given to Apache, but this didn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install --yes apache2
RUN apt-get install --yes perl
RUN perl -MCPAN -e "install DBI"
RUN perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::Pg"
RUN a2enmod cgid
RUN service apache2 restart
WORKDIR /usr/lib/cgi-bin
COPY shipping.pl .
```

**Perl script: shipping.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# load module
use DBI;

# connect
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=shipping;host=192.168.56.3", "postgres", "somepassword", {'RaiseError' => 1});

# execute SELECT query
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT surname FROM surnames");
$sth->execute();

# iterate through resultset
# print values
while(my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "$ref->{'surname'}";
}

# clean up
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: See also [How to configure the docker file to run cgi-script like perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42363767/2173773)

Comment: If the site can't be reached, this isn't a Perl problem. Can you reach any part of the site, including static pages?

Comment: I haven't tried it with a static page yet I will try as soon as I can

Comment: i just tried it and it doesnt seem apache is working right. I copied a html page into both /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ and /var/www/html/ but neither of them seemed to work